# Create a mocked list with objects

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, junit5

I want to create a JUnit test with tests mocked objects:

```
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImplTest {

    private RiskFilterService riskFilterService = null;

    @Before
    public void beforeEachTest() {

        List<RiskFilters> list = new ArrayList<RiskFilters>();

        riskFilterService = Mockito.mock(RiskFilterService.class);

        // put here list of List<RiskFilters> and return it 
    }

    @Test
    public void testBinCountryCheckFilterImpl() {

        List<RiskFilters> filter_list = riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(11, "test");
         // do something                
    }    
}
```

How I can return the list `List<RiskFilters>` when `RiskFilterService` is calle?

Second attempt:

```
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImplTest {

    private RiskFilterService riskFilterService = null;

    @Mock
    List<RiskFilters> mockList = new ArrayList<RiskFilters>();

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeEachTest() {

        //if we don't call below, we will get NullPointerException
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        mockList.add(new RiskFilters());

        riskFilterService = Mockito.mock(RiskFilterService.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBinCountryCheckFilterImpl() {

        when(riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(anyInt(), anyString())).thenReturn(mockList);

        List<RiskFilters> filter_list = riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(11, "BinCountryCheckFilter");

    }
}
```

But I get NPE for `riskFilterService`. Looks like the method with annotation @test is called before @BeforeClass.

Comment: `RiskFilterService` is the class you want to test? And what method you want to mock?

Comment: Yes, I want ot mock the result from `findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType`

Comment: something like: `Mockito.when(riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(anyInt(), anyString()).thenReturn(new ArrayList<RiskFilters>());`

Comment: I get `The method thenReturn(ArrayList<RiskFilters>) is undefined for the type List<RiskFilters>`

Comment: can you post the method you want to test? And what jUnit version do you use?

Comment: I have a question. See the updated post with the second attempt. I get NPE for `riskFilterService` because @Test is called before initialization. How I can fix this?

Comment: @Willem I managed to fix it just NPE problem is left.

Comment: Junit 4 uses  `@Before` and junit 5 `@BeforeAll`

Comment: Well `@BeforeEach` solved the problem.

Comment: You can just replace `private RiskFilterService riskFilterService = null;` with `private RiskFilterService riskFilterService = Mockito.mock(RiskFilterService.class);` and remove your `@Before` method

Comment: Yes i tried it but I have more test in which I have to initialize more test cases with different values.

Comment: By the way if I have for example 4 test methods with `@Test` annotation how I can make Java methods with precondition setup test data with each of them? I can make 4 different Test classes but this is another story....

Comment: The way i do it, is to declare the data inside the @Test method that should be returned. If i have complex object to build i declare a private method inside the test to get the object so i can reuse it in other Test classes. Only for data that is always the same i declare it in a field in the test class.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Looks a standard way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

When a List or any other Collection is required in a unit test, the first question to ask yourself is: should I create a mock for it, or should I create a List or a Collection containing mocks.

When the logic being tested is not using the list, but just passing the list than you can mock it.

Otherwise it is usually better not to mock a List or a Collection but to create a normal one containing mocked objects because it can become very difficult to know which methods of the List or Collections need to be stubbed. Which methods are called when using a for loop to iterate the items, when using an iterator on them, when using a stream on them, ... ? I often use Collections.singletonList or Arrays.asList with mocked parameters to initialise lists when writing unit tests.

I see that you mock the list and then you call the add method to add data to it while setting up the test. It doesn't make sense to add data to a mocked list. You can use Mockito.when to return it when it should be returned, but then you would get in trouble because you might need to stub more methods and it would be hard to know which ones (isEmpty, size, ...). That you are adding a dataobject to list probably means the method being tested is not just passing the list but will access the data in it. In that case, don't mock the list, but mock the data objects which you put in it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you provided very less information. BUt let me put through

you must be having `BinCountryCheckFilter` class. Please Initialise it in your test class and add annotation `@InjectMocks`

```
@InjectMock
private BinCountryCheckFilter binCountryCheckFilter;
```

take         `riskFilterService = Mockito.mock(RiskFilterService.class);` out of `@BeforeClass` and put it openly.

But this will just mock your class and will not test anything. One thing you can test is no of calls made. See below

```
verify(mockList, times(1)).yourMethodName();
```

or add following in your test or before method

```
when(riskFilterService.yurMethodName).thenReturn(your Return value);
```

This way you will be able to mock the data you want.
Let me know if any other clarity needed.

I am not sure of your JUnit version but you can remove

comelete `@BeforeClass` from your code now and

```
 @Mock
    List<RiskFilters> mockList = new ArrayList<RiskFilters>();
```

too.